# Rake clean -- exclude sub directory

Tags: rake

I have a directory tree which looks like the following:

```
|- src
| \- stuff
| \- app
|- target
| \- stuff
| \- app
```

I have the following in a `rakefile`:

```
include 'rake/clean'
CLEAN.include 'target'
CLEAN.exclude 'target/stuff'
```

My intention is to have the tree end up like the following:

```
|- src
| \- stuff
| \- app
|- target
| \- stuff
```

Obviously in my example above this could be done with `CLEAN.include 'target/app'` but my actual layout is more complex.

Is there a way to exclude `target/app` from getting cleaned but still clean everything else in the `target` directory? If not, what is the point of having `CLEAN.exclude` in the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that exclude does not seem to behave as expected.  Here's what I did to work around this:

```
Dir['target/*'].each do |file|
  CLEAN.include file unless file == 'stuff'
end
```